How to fetch HTML content value in XML from staxevent item reader in spring batch
I want to fetch HTML content present inside my XML tag and how can this be achieved by using xml reader? Below are the code I have used and configured.
This is my reader configuration
@Bean
    public StaxEventItemReader<Idt> idtItemReader() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller mtrlMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        mtrlMarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Idt.class);
        StaxEventItemReader<Idt> xmlFileReader = new StaxEventItemReader<Idt>();
        xmlFileReader.setFragmentRootElementName("PROJECT");
        xmlFileReader.setUnmarshaller(mtrlMarshaller);
        xmlFileReader.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        return xmlFileReader;
    }

And I have my pojo like the below structure and use lombok to get getters and setters. The tag DETAIL consists of HTML content like p tag. This needs to be rendered like string and stored in the database. When I have used String it doesn't give any content and displays as empty value. Can't HTML content be rendered as string?
@Data
@XmlRootElement(name = "PROJECT")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Idt implements ResourceAware {
    @XmlElement(name="DETAIL")
    String detail;
}

This is sample of my XML file having this DETAIL content.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PROJECT>   
<DETAIL><p>Detail</p>   
</DETAIL>
</PROJECT>

How can I render this DETAIL tag and need value like having p tag and use it across my processor. This DETAIL tag can have simple string or content like detail enclosed within p tag. On either case, I need to extract data as such and store that in DB.
